# Не получается распарсить значение из списка в json

Tags: python, requests

В Python делаю POST запрос на ресурс. В результате получаю json такого вида:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Operation success",
    "objectIds": [
        "36bf3862-5947-41d1-96b4-b74b8ebf4f4e"
    ],
    "modified": 1704869899
}
```

Мне нужно вытащить значение objectIds и подставить его в url другого запроса (DELETE)

Вот так выглядит POST запрос:

```
post_url = base_url+post_resource
    print(post_url)
    result_post = requests.request("POST", post_url, headers=http_methods_instance.headers, data=json_for_create_new_npa, verify=False)
    print(result_post.text)
    response_json = json.loads(result_post.text)
    object_ids = response_json['objectIds'][0]
    print(object_ids)

    return object_ids
```

А это метод DELETE:

```
@staticmethod
def delete_new_npa(object_ids, url):
    delete_resource = f"/service/registry/legal/document/doc/{object_ids}"
    delete_url = base_url + delete_resource
    print(delete_url)
    result_delete = Http_methods.delete(delete_url, url)
    print(result_delete.text)
    return result_delete
```

Пробовал конструкцию:

```
object_ids = response_json.get('objectIds', [])
print("Object IDs:", object_ids)
```

Но на выходе получается list и выходит ошибка, что 'list' object has no attribute 'json'
Пробовал делать костуркци

Comment: @Zahar не работает. В первом случае ругается 'dict' object has no attribute 'objectIds'
Во втором случае 'list' object has no attribute 'json'

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки с полным трэйсбэком.

Comment: В принципе, такое впечатление, что вы получаете из функции уже распарсенный список айдишников, и зачем-то у этого списка пытаетесь обратится к атрибуту json (которого у списка, очевидно, нет)

Comment: Во-первых попробуйте вместо `response_json = json.loads(result_post.text)` взять просто `response_json = result_post.json()`, во-вторых покажите **полный стек-трейс ошибки**, тут не гадают по пересказу ошибок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с json-форматом есть специальная библиотека json. Ниже на примере покажу как получать данные с запроса в привычный формат `dict`:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
todos = json.loads(response.text)

print(type(todos[0]))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на документацию методов dict](https://stavis-dev.github.io/python/types/python-types-dict/?ysclid=lr7oekdjtu640784342#dictget)

Comment: спасибо, я получил результатом строку, но корневую проблему это не решило. При попытке преобразовать строку через json.loads возникает json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2), код: id_list = response_json.get('objectIds', [])
        id_value = id_list[0] if id_list else None
        print(id_value)
        json.loads(id_value)

Comment: @ToxZyjen Это может произойти, если вы пытаетесь десериализовать некорректный JSON, например, с неверным форматом, отсутствием кавычек вокруг строк, неверным форматом даты, некорректным числовым форматом и т. д.
Убедитесь, что с сервера приходит валидный json ответ